# Background With Changing Elements HTML

Tags: html, css, image, web, background

Sorry if the title makes no sense, I didn't know how to call this issue, lol.

So... I have this android app which shows a parking lot, with the parking layout as the background and some cars showing "inside" each parking when needed. This is easy to build using different layouts for each parking and changing the image sources from empty to a car, etc.

The thing is... I need to replicate this on a web page, And I have no idea how could I build a background and change images on top of it. I suppose I could make a bunch of divs for each parking, changing the img sources when needed and use the parking lot layout as the background for the whole thing, however I don't know if this would be the best practice, and the whole idea doesn't really sound responsive to me.

Any ideas?

I don't expect/need it to change in real time like you can do with Android, but I do need to replicate the idea of changing images programatically on top of a background.

Thanks!

Comment: You're in luck! This is very possible with HTML and CSS, in a similar way to your application. Could you share with us what you've already tried, including any code you've written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real way to overlay images with CSS is by having a relatively displayed container with it's inner image elements absolutely positioned.

Using this idea, it'd be possible to absolutely position the car images on top of your image parking spots.

---

That being said, why don't you create a more abstract representation of this parking lot?

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.available {
  background-color: green;
}

.unavailable {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Parking spot availability</h1>

<p>Green indicates an available spot. Red indicates an unavailable spot.</p>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="available">1</div>
  <div class="unavailable">2</div>
  <div class="available">3</div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, I would recommend using jQuery. Register event handlers for each of your images and adjust the `src` property accordingly. I have provided an example below for review:

```js
$('.car').on('click', function () {
  $(this).prop('src', 'https://placeholdit.co//i/300x150?text=A%20Completely%20New%20Image!&bg=111111');
});
```

```css
.playground {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.car {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="playground">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/200x150?text=The%20Original%20Image" class="car" />
</div>
```